# Doesn't the jvm argument xms mean process won't start if the specified memory is missing?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-arguments

I had set the xms to 32g and xmx to 32g

The program started, but when around 25GB data was loaded into memory, the process was killed by Linux, giving the reason of memory issues.

If 32g was already assigned to the process due to xms being 32g, why did it went out of memory?
Doesn't xms mean allocate this memory in beginning and if you cannot please don't start the process ?

Can someone please explain, why programs fails ?

Comment: How much memory does your system have? Assuming you have 32GB available and assign everything to the JVM the OS might still kill the JVM because it doesn't have anything for itself. Also note that the JVM will use more than just the heap memory, so if you set xms to 32GB it will actually use more (how much depends on other settings).

Comment: Try adding the `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` option.

Answer (score 5):

"Allocating memory" really means "allocating virtual address space".  Modern operating systems separate the address space used by a process from physical memory.

So, with -Xms32G, you've got 32G of address space.

Actual memory is allocated in pages and on demand, which generally means that something has to actually 'touch' a page before memory is 'committed' to the page.

Thus in reality, memory is only being committed as needed. And if the OS decides it is under real-memory pressure at the time, you're likely to get killed.

You can force the JVM to touch each page at startup by using the JVM option -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch.  The likely effect of this will be that the JVM process starts and gets killed during its initialization, before your program is entered at main(). You still can't get the memory, you just find out sooner.

The OOM killer being what it is, it is also possible that the pretouch will go ok, your code will run, but at some later time due to other system activity, the kernel will decide it's critically low on available resources, and since you're probably the largest process around, there's a target on your back.

Comment: Do not confuse virtual memory with [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). Having virtual memory does not imply that there must be overcommitment and a system without overcommitment doesn’t need an “OOM killer”.

Comment: The OP asked about Linux.  Given the fact of his asking, it's pretty certain the system over-commits.

Comment: Obviously, there’s memory overcommitment involved. Nobody said otherwise. But your answer doesn’t even mention it but rather pretends that the issue was a general property of systems with memory virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `-Xms` and `-Xmx` control the *heap* of your java process. A java process need memory for other things too, like off heap allocation, GC structures, etc. What this means is that when you set your application to a heap of `1GB`, your java process is going to need *more* than that.

Second point is that `-Xms` controls the *committed* memory in the virtual space. Virtual space for a 64 bit CPU is huge. Committed memory becomes *resident* in a lazy fashion (resident is actual in RAM, for example). So when you set `-Xmx` and `-Xms`, you will get a portion of virtual memory allocated as needed.

You should carefully read the logs on this part:

> giving the reason of memory issues

you probably are killed by the OOM Killer, which kills the process, which you already know (from the above) that needs more than the heap.

If you want to allocate memory and make it resident, add the `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` flag. This will make your process start a lot slower though and in general, is not a great idea. It has its benefits in various applications.

Comment: I’d rather reconfigure the operating system to not do overcommitment. Then, the failure to commit more memory would lead to an ordinary `OutOfMemoryError`, rather than randomly killed processes. Note that `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` may reduce the likelihood of such a kill but can’t prevent it.

Comment: @Holger why not? This is exactly what swap is for, but even without it, it could work just fine. For example, in k8s ( until 1.22 where swap exists ), almost everyone deploys pods with a cumulative `requests.limits` that is larger then the RAM you have

Comment: Overcommitment has nothing to do with swap memory. Overcommitment means, the commited memory isn’t actually available, not even with swap. And the OOM Killer just kills randomly, which isn’t surprising given that there is no single guilty program if the amount of memory allocated by *all programs together* exceeds the available memory. `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` only ensures that there is enough memory left to back up the initial heap size, but doesn’t say, how much unbacked committed memory the other processes already have or will commit in the future. So the java process still may get killed.

Comment: @Holger I am saying that the spikes are handled by swap, not that the memory has to be available in swap. Otherwise, agreed.

Comment: Sure, swap can handle spikes, but that’s unrelated to overcommitment. You can disable overcommitment and still use swap. Then, you don’t need pre-touch.